# is quotient ring ℤ/(5) the same as field ℤ/5ℤ?

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is a ring homomorphism f: ℤ -> ℤ/5ℤ × ℤ/5ℤ. I get the kernel is (5). And also I get that kernel f is an ideal of ℤ. Now, I wonder what the relation between the quotient ring ℤ/(5) and the field ℤ/5ℤ is. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they are one and the same, or if you prefer: the quotient ring $\;\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\;$ is in fact a field.

Comment: What definitions of these two rings do you employ that makes the appear to be not "the same"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Whether you acknowledge it or not, nonzero elements in the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ have multiplicative inverses, making the ring in fact a field.